# QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal warning for legit code

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am fairly new to Qt Framework and I am still in the process of learning. While searching for tutorials , I stumbled upon a series of videos teaching the basics of Qt along with a project of making a calculator . Although the calculator seems to be working fine I get this , sort of , warnings

```
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_pushButton_unary_released()
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_pushButton_binary_released()
```

i've tried everything but nothing seems to work . I am really frustrated with it . Any help with this would be appreciated . BTW I've attached the code of mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

double firstnum ;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

    ui->setupUi(this);
   connect(ui->pushButton_0 , SIGNAL(released()),this,SLOT(digits_released()));
   connect(ui->pushButton_1 , SIGNAL(released()),this,SLOT(digits_released()));
   connect(ui->pushButton_2 , SIGNAL(released()),this,SLOT(digits_released()));
   connect(ui->pushButton_3 , SIGNAL(released()),this,SLOT(digits_released()));
   connect(ui->pushButton_4 , SIGNAL(released()),this,SLOT(digits_released()));
   connect(ui->pushButton_5 , SIGNAL(released()),this,SLOT(digits_released()));
   connect(ui->pushButton_6 , SIGNAL(released()),this,SLOT(digits_released()));
   connect(ui->pushButton_7 , SIGNAL(released()),this,SLOT(digits_released()));
   connect(ui->pushButton_8 , SIGNAL(released()),this,SLOT(digits_released()));
   connect(ui->pushButton_9 , SIGNAL(released()),this,SLOT(digits_released()));
   connect(ui->pushButton_plusminus , SIGNAL(released()),this,SLOT(on_pushButton_unary_released()));
   connect(ui->pushButton_percent , SIGNAL(released()),this,SLOT(on_pushButton_unary_released()));
   connect(ui->pushButton_plus , SIGNAL(released()),this,SLOT(on_pushButton_binary_released()));
   connect(ui->pushButton_minus, SIGNAL(released()),this,SLOT(on_pushButton_binary_released()));
   connect(ui->pushButton_multiply , SIGNAL(released()),this,SLOT(on_pushButton_binary_released()));
   connect(ui->pushButton_divide , SIGNAL(released()),this,SLOT(on_pushButton_binary_released()));

   ui->pushButton_divide->setCheckable(true);
   ui->pushButton_minus->setCheckable(true);
   ui->pushButton_plus->setCheckable(true);
   ui->pushButton_multiply->setCheckable(true);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;

}

void MainWindow::digits_released(){
  QPushButton *button = (QPushButton*)sender();
  double labelNumber ;
  QString newLabel ;
  if(ui->pushButton_plus->isChecked() || ui->pushButton_minus->isChecked()
     || ui->pushButton_divide->isChecked()
     || ui->pushButton_multiply->isChecked())
  {
      labelNumber = button->text().toDouble();
  }
  else
  {
  labelNumber = (ui->label->text() + button->text()).toDouble();
  newLabel = QString::number(labelNumber, 'g' , 15);
  ui->label->setText(newLabel);
  }
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_decimal_released()
{
    QString decimal = QString(".");
    if (ui->label->text().contains(decimal))
    {
    }
    else
    {
    ui->label->setText(ui->label->text() + ".");
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_unary_released()
{
    QPushButton * button = (QPushButton*) sender();
    double labelNumber ;
    QString newLabel ;

    if (button->text() == "+/-")
    {
        labelNumber = ui->label->text().toDouble();
        labelNumber = labelNumber * -1 ;
        newLabel = QString::number(labelNumber, 'g' , 15);
        ui->label->setText(newLabel);
    }
    else if (button->text() == "%") {
        labelNumber = ui->label->text().toDouble();
        labelNumber = labelNumber * 0.01  ;
        newLabel = QString::number(labelNumber, 'g' , 15);
        ui->label->setText(newLabel);
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_C_released()
{
    ui->label->setText("0");
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_binary_released()
{
    QPushButton * button = (QPushButton*) sender();
    firstnum = ui->label->text().toDouble();
    button->setChecked(true);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_equal_released()
{
    double secondnum , labelNumber ;
    QString  newlabel ;
    secondnum = ui->label->text().toDouble();
    if (ui->pushButton_plus->isChecked())
    {
        labelNumber = firstnum + secondnum ;
        newlabel = QString::number(labelNumber , 'g' , 15);
        ui->label->setText(newlabel);
        ui->pushButton_plus->setChecked(false);

    }
    else if (ui->pushButton_minus->isChecked())
    {
        labelNumber = firstnum - secondnum ;
        newlabel = QString::number(labelNumber , 'g' , 15);
        ui->label->setText(newlabel);
        ui->pushButton_minus->setChecked(false);
    }
    else if (ui->pushButton_divide->isChecked())
    {
        labelNumber = firstnum / secondnum ;
        newlabel = QString::number(labelNumber , 'g' , 15);
        ui->label->setText(newlabel);
        ui->pushButton_divide->setChecked(false);
    }
    else if (ui->pushButton_multiply->isChecked())
    {
        labelNumber = firstnum * secondnum ;
        newlabel = QString::number(labelNumber , 'g' , 15);
        ui->label->setText(newlabel);
        ui->pushButton_multiply->setChecked(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using the [new signal slot syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax). That way you'll get easier to read compile time errors rather than runtime errors.

Comment: I looked at the documentation for the new signal slot syntax but I'm bit confused. Could you maybe elaborate on that or give a sort of  practical sample code for the new slot syntax ?

Comment: [qt-5 signals and slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slots named as *"on_something** are handled in a special way by QMetaObject which uses It's reflection mechanisms to connect them to the right control and signal.

The sintax is actually on_objectName_signal. So the error you see in the console is because moc didn't find an object named "pushButton_unary" to attempt the automatic connection.

Since you are connecting your signals to slots manually just rename the slots avoiding that syntax (e.g. name the slot "onUnaryButtonRelesed").